# How do I enter a value in one class and have it enumerated in another class to output the proper info?

Tags: java, enumeration

I have created 2 classes one that is the enumeration class to determine what the grades someone received are and the other is supposed to be a simple program to call it and display the gpa value and the pass or fail value
here is the enumeration class

```
package root;
public enum LetterGrade
{
a ("A", 4.0, true), aMinus ("A-", 3.7, true), 
bPlus ("B+", 3.3, true), b ("B", 3.0, true), bMinus ("B-", 2.7, true), 
cPlus ("C+", 2.3, true), c ("C", 2.0, true), cMinus ("C-", 1.7, true), 
dPlus ("D+", 1.3, false), d ("D", 1.0, false), dMinus ("D-", 0.7, false), 
f ("F", 0.0, false);
private final String grade;
private final double points;
private final boolean pass;
private LetterGrade (String letterGrade, double gradePoints, boolean isPass)
{
    grade = letterGrade;
    points = gradePoints;
    pass = isPass;
}
public String getletterGrade ()
{
    return grade;
}
public boolean isPass()
{
    return pass;
}   
public double getgradePoints ()
{
    return points;
}   
}
```

here is the other class

```
package root;
import root.LetterGrade;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ch6PP5_RobertSaunders {

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String grade;
    System.out.println("Please input the grade you recieved.");
    grade = keyboard.next();
    LetterGrade = new LetterGrade(String grade);
    System.out.println("");

}

}
```

I am stuck on how to call the enum values, my test inputs at the moment are A, b, A+, aPlus, f, and e but i have no idea how to set them up as an input for a test yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a method to get the `LetterGrade` from a `double` to the enum. Something like,

```
public static LetterGrade fromDouble(double grade) {
    int len = values().length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (grade >= values()[i].getgradePoints())
            return values()[i];
    }
    return LetterGrade.f;
}
```

And I suggest you override `toString()` like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return grade;
}
```

Then your `main()` method can use it like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input the grade you recieved.");
    double grade = keyboard.nextDouble();
    LetterGrade lg = LetterGrade.fromDouble(grade);
    System.out.println(lg);
}
```

Comment: You just did someone else's homework. Only fair if you get the degree now... ;)

Comment: Or, more seriously: What's the point of providing a copy & paste ready answer to a beginner's question?

Comment: @jangroth This is only a little more then 10 lines of code. OP actually wrote the `enum`.

Comment: This is homework, but it is homework I have submitted already without this portion attached. I was trying to better understand how to do something that I got snagged on and I am attempting to improve on my deficiencies.

Answer (score 0):

Think about adding a (`static`) method to `LetterGrade` that retrieves the correct instance based on the user input:

```
LetterGrade usersGrade = LetterGrade.retrieveFromInput(grade);
```

You probably need to utilize a few of the helper methods that [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) provides...